# Interface inside Interface typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular, i've trying to produce some result with the interface class.

```
export interface Header {
   parentTitles: string;
   childHeaders: ChildHeader[];
   titleIcon: string;
   url: string;
  }

export interface ChildHeader {
   childTitles: string;
   siblingHeaders: SiblingHeader[];
   icon: string;
   url: string;
 }


export interface SiblingHeader {
  siblingTitles: string[];
  icon: string;
  url: string;
```

}

On the comp.ts file

```
 headers: Header = [
   {
  parentTitles: 'Settings',
  childHeaders: ChildHeader = [{
    childTitles: 'General Setup',
    siblingHeaders: SiblingHeader = [{
      siblingTitles: ['Vessel', 'Port', 'Owner', 'Engine Type', 
    'Vessel Type'],
      icon: '',
      url: ''
    }],
    icon: '',
    url: 'home/general-setup'
      }]
   }

  ];
```

So the  ChildHeader and SiblingHeader is undefined, how to solve this!.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't annotate types inside an object literal.  Your `headers` is a `Header[]` and not a `Header`.  I expect you will get lots of compile time errors you need to fix.  When you say "`ChildHeader` and `SiblingHeader` is undefined", do you mean at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an object instance, the syntax is `propertName: value`. You cannot use types as values. The error you are getting is that, for example `SiblingHeader` is being used as a value, but it's not a value -- it's a type.

However, since you already have `header: Header`, you've already declared the `header` object as a header which means that its `childHeaders` property is already an array of `ChildHeader`, which themselves are arrays of objects with the `siblingHeaders` property as an array of `SiblingHeader`. That is to say you don't need properties to have types in object literals since they are derived from the type of the object itself.

```
const headers: Header[] = [{
  parentTitles: 'Settings',
  childHeaders: [{
    childTitles: 'General Setup',
    siblingHeaders: [{
      siblingTitles: ['Vessel', 'Port', 'Owner', 'Engine Type',  'Vessel Type'],
      icon: '',
      url: ''
    }],
    icon: '',
    url: 'home/general-setup'
  }]
}];
```